# Make an automatic POST/GET request with java

Tags: java, html-parsing, http-post, http-get

Take a look to this page for example

http://www.hwdyk.com/quiz/m/2534/the-avengers-hard-version

the thing I want to do is to call the Start Quiz Button in code , and to process the response...

Then I want to select some of the four checkboxes and have some code that will do an automatic press to continue button ( I guess that is new GET/POST request)...

I am new to this and I need some guidelines how to start

any ideas how can I do this in java code ?

I need to develop some java application that will have the start uri and than it will do automatic GET or POST requests

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 2):

If i have correctly understand what you want to do java is not the language you should use to do this. You should use javascript to select the checkboxes, click on the button and send the results with get or post. Just take a look at jquery http://jquery.com/ too